# What is the meaning of predecessor in the info? is it the latest finalized block?

Tags: smart-rollup, rollup, scoru

What is the meaning of `predecessor` in the info? is it the latest finalized block? Or the one before that?

Question from Slack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one before that. Because we cannot the head, the `Info_per_level` has an impact on the block hash. You cannot know in advance the hash so you cannot push the message in the inbox